# How to do routing between the instances in AWS using Route Table?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routing, cisco

I have built the following model below.
There are 4 instances which have CSR 1000v router deployed in 4 created subnets (green CIDR) that have 28 as a mask. I have created other subnets in order to create interfaces to these routers (blue CIDR). I have attached each interface to its proper instance.

Because the `ip route` showed direct connections between 2 instances after the interfaces' configuration, I could not ping the other interfaces from any instance of the network.
I could only `ping` from `Instance 1` the interfaces of `Instance 2` and vice-versa, but the others are unreachable.

[image]

I also tried the static route which did not work either. I tried to do a custom Route Table `Destination` as subnet 1 where the `Instance 1` which is deployed is `172.31.0.0/28`, and the target is one of the interfaces that is attached to `Instance 1`. Like the above table:

`|--------------------|---------------------|--------------|
|    Destination     |        Target       | Status       |
|--------------------|---------------------|--------------|
|   172.31.0.0/16    |        Local        | Active       |
|--------------------|---------------------|--------------|
|   172.31.0.0/28    |eni-01688e43d190ca787|              |
|--------------------|---------------------|--------------|`

Then I got this message error

`API error message
cannot create a more specific route for 172.31.0.0/28 than CIDR 172.31.0.0/16 associated with the VPC, with association-id vpc-cidr-assoc-9ee5e5f6, in route table rtb-06de44ffbb5c66799`

Note that, I allowed `ICMP` traffic in all instances, and I disable `Source/Dest`, how can I do the pinging here, or how to use the Route table in my case ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this setup?

Comment: @MattHouser , first I need to make sure that these routers are all connected to each other as the topology above, then I create instances that host **Network Functions** which might be connected to one or two **CSR router**, then from an **End-Point traffic** (which might be an EC2 instance), I send a _traffic_ that has to pass through a particular **Network Functions** then that _traffic_ will be forwarded to the **CSR routers** then to its destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite confusing to have all the routers inside the same VPC and I'm not surprised it doesn't work because VPC routing has some limitations.

If I were you I would:

- Create **4 different VPCs** inside your AWS account, with 4 distinct CIDRs
- Create **1 CSR per VPC**, each with a *Public / Elastic IP*
- Link them through the Public IPs (you can restrict access through Security Groups), optionally over a VPN or PPP or some other kind of tunnel.

That will be much closer to a *real world scenario* where you would have a router for each LAN, the LANs have different CIDRs, you can have EC2 instances inside the LANs, and it will all be much tidier and easier to operate.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Not sure about AWS, but Azure does not have a Real Network, so when you connect Cisco CSR together within a Resource Group or VNET, it does not mean that they will be able to route traffic as they would in a Real World. More like a Software Defined Lan, instead of physical connections. Lot of tweaking required to make things work.

Comment: @AbuZaid, 
It turned out that I could ping the other interfaces from any instance except few. From `Instance 2`, the pining **was not successful** with `Instance 1` interface `172.31.1.5` which is so weird because both interfaces are in the same subnet `172.31.1.0/28`, as well as with `Instance 4` `172.31.1.29`.
From `Instance 3` the pining **is failed** only with `Instance 4` interface `172.31.1.56`.
From `Instance 4` the pining **is failed** with `Instance 2` interface `172.31.1.27`, and with `Instance 3` interface `172.31.1.61`.

Comment: @MLu
well, your proposition can be used. But, I have some issues with understanding how it can be applied in my case. After building this topology, I have to make sure that I can ping from any instance to another, and if I send a traffic from `Instance 1` to `Instance 4`, the path can be chosen, either through `Instance 2 or 3` to reach the destination. Also, I would like to read out (monitoring) the load of these links after having such a traffic passed through the links.

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia I wouldn’t spend too much time on trying to rectify your setup. Nodes in the same VPC are able to talk to each other. Now you’re trying to overlay a virtual network over it with the same CIDR as your VPC. Don’t. Put the CSRs in 4 separate VPCs and you’ll have a much more realistic and more predictable setup.

Comment: @MLu thanks for the reply. I will try it out. One more thing, if I do it exactly like you just described earlier, how can I measure the loads on the IP links between CSRs if they are literally not connected to each other via interfaces?

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia You always measure loads on the interfaces connected to the link - this will be no different. If you want you can give your CSR two interfaces - one in a public subnet for linking with the other CSRs and one on the internal subnet for comms with the internal EC2s. You can also create a PPP or GRE or IPIP or similar link between the CSRs which will present as a new interface and you can then measure the load on that.

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia BTW if this discussion helped I wouldn't mind if you accepted and upvoted my answer. That's the ServerFault way to reward someone for the time they spent helping you. Thanks!